# SOLVED: Which RegexExtract parameters to extract number with different length & format

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to extract a number in Google Sheets with the RegexExtract function.
The challenge is the number length varies from 3 to 6, the number can be decimal with a . or be more than 1000 then with a , for 1,000

I managed to find a way for 4/5 use-cases but can't figure it out for the integer without . or ,

```
$63,284 Mil       63,284    REGEXEXTRACT(E22,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+") 
$3,552 Mil        3,552     REGEXEXTRACT(E23,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+") 
$386 Mil          #N/A      REGEXEXTRACT(E24,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+") 
$192.7 Mil        192.7     REGEXEXTRACT(E25,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+") 
$71.9 Mil         71.9      REGEXEXTRACT(E62,"[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(E22:E62, "[^0-9,.]",))
```

and see if that works?

The formula removes every character from the source range that is not a digit, comma or (decimal) point.

Comment: That's awesome JPV, it works !!!!
Big thank you, I spent hours trying to solve this.

I'm using it on a line formula regexreplace(E22, "[^0-9,.]",) because I will divide this value by another value.

Super useful. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Rafa, sorry, I didn't know about the Accept button. 
I just accepted & thanks JPV for the super valuable help :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+|\d+")))
```

[image]